# How to generate random numbers array that contains 3-sigma outliers?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to test some classification functions and to do so I need to generate non-uniform random numbers such that there will be outliers (mean +- 3 * SD).  So far what I've seen is only random distributions with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.rand(100)
s = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(10000,1))
```

results
    [10, 20, 30, ... ]

```
s[(abs(s - s.mean())) > (3*s.std())]
```

Here I would expect to see 30 outliers, but yet the results yield an empty array.

Comment: NumPy has a number of distributions you can take random samples from: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/routines.random.html. For example, to take random samples from the standard normal distribution you can do `np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)`

Comment: @SeanTakafuji is right. Numpy has a lot of useful distribution functions (note that the random module does as well). Are you looking for a specific distribution?

Comment: No specific distribution in mind, I'm looking for data that will produce outliers. @JackMoody

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can generate a lot of distributions from `numpy.random`, as for outliers, they are generated based on their probability as every other element. e.g. If you generate a 10k normal sample you will have ~30 outliers

Comment: @Mstaino, I've updated the question to show what I've tried.  Maybe my filter is incorrect?

Comment: "I need to generate non-uniform random numbers" Then why are you using `randint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is correct: the problem is that the standard deviation of a u[niform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) is `(b-a)/sqrt(12)` (a random integer sample in a wide range is very similar to a uniform distribution). Therefore mean +- 3 times the standard deviation **will always lay outside the boundaries of your sample**.

You need either an unbounded distribution and/or something with a more centered shape. This examples can work (sizes may vary and will depend on your distribution):

```
# power of 0-1 random
s = np.random.random(10000)**5
s[np.abs(s - s.mean()) > s.std() * 3].size
>> 164

# average of 6 uniforms
s=np.sum(np.random.randint(0,1000, size=10000) for i in range(6))/6
s[np.abs(s - s.mean()) > s.std() * 3].size
>> 16

# And of course unbounded distributions such as the normal:
s = np.random.normal(size=10000)
s[np.abs(s - s.mean()) > s.std() * 3].size
>> 27
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a good old [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)? Sampling from a normal distribution can be done with [`numpy.random.standard_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_normal.html) or [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html):

```
import numpy as np

s = np.random.standard_normal(size=10000)

outliers = s[(abs(s - s.mean())) > (3 * s.std())]
print(outliers)
```

Comment: @JürgenK. The question author clarified later on in the comments that he/she has "No specific distribution in mind, I'm looking for data that will produce outliers."

Comment: @JürgenK. Could you please explain why you believe this answer is not applicable? The code in this answer is near-identical to code in the 'accepted answer' by Mstaino.

Comment: I don't understand why the above answer was accepted either. The distribution in both cases is the same